# Socket.io + node JS = Error during handshake: error code 500

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, socket.io, azure-web-app-service

I was working on Socket.io and node jS to develop a chat web app. It worked locally but I have faced many issues when I deployed my changes to Azure app service.
I am creating a secure connection on port 443. I have resolved other issues but I can't resolve this one.
This the error I'm getting in console on client side.

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500

This is how I'm connecting on server side

```
var socket = io.connect("https://mydomain:443", {transports: ['websocket'], secure: true, port: '443'});
```

and this is my server.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require("passport");
const users = require("./routes/api/users");
const base = require("./routes/api/base");
const leads = require("./routes/api/leads");
const requests = require("./routes/api/requests");
const offApp = require("./routes/api/offApp");
const chat = require("./routes/api/chat");
const chatSocket = require("./routes/socket/chat");
const path = require("path"); // on top
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors')
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  pfx: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pfx'),
  passphrase: 'password'
};

app.use(cors());

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var client = require("socket.io").listen(server);
client.origins('*:*');
client.set('transports', ['websocket']);
server.listen(443);

// Bodyparser middleware
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB Config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(
    db,
    { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {

      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      console.log('MongoDB connected');
      chatSocket(db, client);
    });

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Passport config
require("./config/passport")(passport);

// Routes
app.use("/api/users", users);
app.use("/api/base", base);
app.use("/api/leads", leads);
app.use("/api/requests", requests);
app.use("/api/offapp", offApp);
app.use("/api/chat", chat);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.static("client/build")); // change this if your dir structure is different
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server up and running on port ${port} !`));
```

I have checked the logs, there are no errors there.

Comment: https://www.programwitherik.com/socket-io-tutorial-with-node-js-and-express/#serverhelloworld

Comment: Try replacing ```var client = require("socket.io").listen(server);``` with ```var client = require('socket.io')(server);```. I am not sure about this but in your error message why is it not showing port in connection url ? Give it a try

Comment: @Vipulw I'm going to test what you have suggested. Port is not showing because port 443. It is default port https for my web app. I think that is why port is not showing. do you think this could be the problem?

Comment: @Vipulw I tried what you said but same error :(

Comment: I think you should run your node app on some other port let's say 3000 and make server configuration such that every request to domain is redirected to localhost:3000. This way from client side while connecting to webscoket use just ```https://example.com```